# Check whether the data source is null or not in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a system for a small shop to store sales data. When I click addToStock button, the current record should update in my dataset.

```
Private Sub AddStockBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStockBtn.Click
    Dim Size, Stock As Integer
    Dim stock_check As Boolean
    stock_check = False
    Try
        Size = Integer.Parse(SizeTxt.Text)
        Stock = Integer.Parse(StockTxt.Text)

        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowName As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") + Stock
                StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
                TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
                stock_check = True
            End If
        Next

        If (Not stock_check) Then
            Dim no As Integer
            no = StockBindingSource.Count + 1
            StockBindingSource.AddNew()
            StockBindingSource.Current("No") = no
            StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
                Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
                If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                    StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                    StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
                End If
            Next
            StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
            StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
            StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid size or stock")
    End Try
End Sub
```

This code works fine if there is data in the stock table. But if the stock table is empty/first time I enter data to stock table, it occures a System.NullReferenceException. Please help.

Error occur here,

```
If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then
```

This code should run first time only,

```
            StockBindingSource.Current("No") = 1
            StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
                Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
                If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                    StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                    StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
                End If
            Next
            StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
            StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
            StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
```

Comment: Can you tell on which line it fails

Comment: `If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then`   Always it fails here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your stock is empty at the beginning so you cannot ask for the current size in the stock

```
StockBindingSource.Current("Size")
```

So you need to check first if it is null or not. If it is, it means that you didn't add any stock yet which happen later in your code.
Try this

```
Private Sub AddStockBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStockBtn.Click
Dim Size, Stock As Integer
Dim stock_check As Boolean
stock_check = False
Try
    Size = Integer.Parse(SizeTxt.Text)
    Stock = Integer.Parse(StockTxt.Text)

if StockBindingSource IsNot Nothing Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
        Dim rowName As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
        If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then
            StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") + Stock
            StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
            stock_check = True
        End If
    Next
End If 

    If (Not stock_check) Then
        Dim no As Integer
        no = StockBindingSource.Count + 1
        StockBindingSource.AddNew()
        StockBindingSource.Current("No") = no
        StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
            End If
        Next
        StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
        StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
        StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
        TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid size or stock")
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: It gives,  `Error 2 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. Operands must be reference or nullable types`

Comment: Try:
if StockBindingSource isNot Nothing Then

Comment: One time it worked but it is not working agin. Gives the same exception

Comment: `Object variable or With block variable not set.` After first time, this error appears as an exception. It seems to be a bug.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316478

Comment: It is another issue. Once you solved the first one, you encountered another issue. The solution I gave was for the first one and it solved it

Comment: On which line it happens?

Comment: Same line `If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then`

Comment: What I need to do is, I have to check whether the datasource contains nothing. If that is the case a new record should add. If the source contains data, I need to check is there any stock for that ID and size. If that is excist, Then stock should replace(For loop). Else need to add a new record.

Comment: Check in debug which object is null. Is it rowName? is it StockBindingSource?

Comment: I used your code. But when i enter data for first time(No data in the database), it goes to catch. Shows the exception Invalid size or stock

Comment: You catch block is confusing since when an exception occurred, it doesn't mean for sure that size or stock are incorrect. Change it to display the exception message

Comment: Yeah thanks. Need to change it. When I use IsNot nothing, If it doesnot contains anything, it response to the IsNot nothing. Why is that?

Comment: If there is not any data, StockBindingsource.count is 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found the answer.

Comment: Ok, great so I am stopping to check

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Thanks for the help ehh.

```
 Private Sub AddStockBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStockBtn.Click
    Dim Size, Stock As Integer
    Dim stock_check As Boolean
    stock_check = False
    Size = Integer.Parse(SizeTxt.Text)
    Stock = Integer.Parse(StockTxt.Text)

    If (StockBindingSource.Count = 0) Then
        StockBindingSource.AddNew()
        StockBindingSource.Current("No") = 1
        StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
            End If
        Next
        StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
        StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
        StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
        TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)

    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowName As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") + Stock
                StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
                TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
                stock_check = True
            End If
        Next

        If (Not stock_check) Then
            Dim no As Integer
            no = StockBindingSource.Count + 1
            StockBindingSource.AddNew()
            StockBindingSource.Current("No") = no
            StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
                Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
                If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                    StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                    StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
                End If
            Next
            StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
            StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
            StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```